# Updating Locale language swift

Tags: swift, swift5, locate

I get Locale.current.languageCode, but I would like also to set that value. How I can do it?

```swift
let currentLanguage = Locale.current.languageCode
```

I use:

```swift
Defaults[.language] = "En"
MOLH.setLanguageTo("en")
```

Answer (score 1):

i do not think that you can change the current Locale language, just a user can change their language/locale in settings.

```swift
static var current: Locale { get }
```